Gmail mail received date displayed wrong every time but after download email in eml file shows proper email date
I am facing issue with the my gmail account that date of received email was not proper and after downloading that email in .eml format that shows proper email.
I am not able to understand, is there any setting available in gmail to fix this?
I have downloaded email and open in mail app

Try to login in mac chrome browser


StackOverflow is for questions related to code programming, but this is not a programming issue. Try asking on [su] instead.
